# Problema en CSS con Position Absolute, el contenido se sobrepone con los demás contenidos

Tags: html, css, scss, html-tabla, css-transform

Quería utilizar un código que vi en Youtube "Como hacer un Menú de Navegación con Tabs" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh94Osf1hvU&t=191s). Pero al momento de crear el menú utilizan position absolute y relative (CREO que ese es el problema). Lo que pasa es que el contenido se sobrepone al footer por ejemplo.

[image: Esto es lo que sucede, es como si no reconociera que existe un footer y si coloca por encima]

Ese es el error que se me presenta, es como si el menú no identificará que debajo de él existen elementos, y no sé como solucionarlo.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de solucionar ese error, lo agradecería de antemano.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="lbl-menu">
      <label for="radio1">Inicio</label>
      <label for="radio2">Servicio</label>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" checked/>
      <div class="tab1">
        <h2>Inicio</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum et
          atque corrupti repellat beatae facere tempore mollitia ducimus
          nulla laudantium eveniet, provident debitis. Fugit nisi minus
          laborum delectus autem esse.
        </p>
      </div>

      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
      <div class="tab2">
        <h2>Servicio</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum et
          atque corrupti repellat beatae facere tempore mollitia ducimus
          nulla laudantium eveniet, provident debitis. Fugit nisi minus
          laborum delectus autem esse.
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
width: 100%; /* Ocupe el 100% del ancho */
max-width: 700px;
margin: auto; /* Centrado en el medio de la pagina */
margin-top: 100px;/* Separacion con el borde superior */
}
.lbl-menu{
background-color: #234; /* Color de fondo del Menu donde estan los label (Inicio y 
Servicio) */
}

.lbl-menu label{
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px; /* Espaciado interno de los label */
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.lbl-menu label:hover{
background: #28435d;
}

.content{
position: relative;/* Despues colocaremos que nuestro contenido interno este 
absoluto, y asi siempre quede dentro del contenedor padre  */
}

.content div{
position: absolute;
line-height: 1.8;
transition: all 600ms ease;
opacity: 0; /* Para que por defecto no aparezca ninguno */
visibility: hidden; /* Para ocultarlo */
transform: scale(0.90);
padding: 30px;
background-color:#fff;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#radio1, #radio2{
display: none;
}

#radio1:checked ~ .tab1, #radio2:checked ~ .tab2{
opacity: 1; /* Cuando damos clic en algun Label, que aparezca la informacion */
visibility: visible;
transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: ¡Hola Luis! Prueba a poner clear:both al footer y/o a darle una altura mínima a .content que ocupe lo que los elementos absolute necseitan. Con absolute estás sacando los divs del flujo de la página y solo el elemento con relative cuenta para el navegador para medir el alto del contenedor.

Comment: No aparece el footer en ese código HTML